# Como rellenar con ceros en los meses que no tengo datos

Tags: javascript, sql

Quiero hacer un reporte de barras lo cual es de enero a diciembre (12 meses) sobre las ventas al crédito y contado por cada mes.

Solo tengo data de un mes y de los restos no. como rellenaria de esos meses con ceros.

Como tengo data de solo un mes me sale esto:

```
MES CONTADOS CREDITOS
05    23       2
```

Quiero así:

```
MES CONTADOS CREDITOS
01     0        0
02     0        0
03     0        0
04     0        0
05     23       2
06     0        0
07     0        0
08     0        0
09     0        0
10     0        0
11     0        0
12     0        0
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    VENTA.MES, SUM(VENTA.CONTADO) AS CONTADO, SUM(VENTA.CREDITO) AS CREDITO 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, '%m') AS MES, 
            (CASE WHEN TIPO_PAGO = 'contado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CONTADO, 
            (CASE WHEN TIPO_PAGO = 'cretido' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CREDITO 
        FROM VENTA
    ) AS VENTA 
ORDER BY VENTA.MES
```

Insertar Aquí:

```
type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",   "Ago", "Set", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"],
                datasets: [{
                        label: 'Al Contado',
                        backgroundColor: '#3EB9DC',
                        data: [10, 14, 6, 7, 13, 9, 13, 16, 11, 8, 12, 9]
                    }, {
                        label: 'Al Fiado',
                        backgroundColor: '#EBEFF3',
                        data: [12, 14, 6, 7, 13, 6, 13, 16, 10, 8, 11, 12]
                    }]

            }
```

Comment: Si tenes data de solo un mes por que necesitas hacer un reporte de todo el año? Suena extraño y no muy usable. Pero, capaz es solo un ejemplo y a lo que te referias es que te vienen datos de meses de forma variable. Entonces lo que podes hacer es inicializar un array de 12 elementos todos con 0 y usar el mes (mes - 1) como indice del array para setear los valores que no son 0.
arrayReporte[mes-1] = valorMes. Y luego le pasas ese array de datos a tu reporte.

Comment: Y si quiero un reporte por días. Es decir quiero que me muestre los 7 días que pasaron contando el hoy. Como seria en es caso. Por favor. Gracias. Las columnas de mi tabla Venta son (tipo_Pago = 'Contado' o 'Credito', Fecha )

Comment: Osea otro reporte diferente a este que estas pidiendo? Y como te llegan los datos? Osea si tenes datos incompletos pero tenes que poner todo el rango, lo primero que tenes que hacer es inicializar el rango y luego pisar los valores que si tenes. Si tenes que para Enero tenes datos en algunos dias nada mas, inicializas el array con los dias de enero todos en 0 y pisas los dias que tenes.

Comment: Cómo es la query que estás ejecutando para obtener esos valores?

Comment: SELECT VENTA.MES, SUM(VENTA.CONTADO) AS CONTADO, SUM(VENTA.CREDITO) AS CREDITO FROM 
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, '%m')AS MES, (CASE WHEN TIPO_PAGO = 'contado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CONTADO,
(CASE WHEN TIPO_PAGO = 'cretido' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CREDITO
FROM VENTA) AS VENTA ORDER BY VENTA.MES

Comment: **¿Qué motor de base de datos utilizas?** La respuesta puede ser diferente para diferentes motores. Por favor, edita tu pregunta e incluye el motor en las etiquetas. Un saludo.

Comment: En éste caso estoy utilizando mysql

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar `GROUP BY` para agrupar los meses y mostrarlos aunque no tuvieran resultado en la query, quedando así:

```
SELECT 
    VENTA.MES, SUM(VENTA.CONTADO) AS CONTADO, SUM(VENTA.CREDITO) AS CREDITO 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, '%m') AS MES, 
            (CASE WHEN TIPO_PAGO = 'contado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CONTADO, 
            (CASE WHEN TIPO_PAGO = 'cretido' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CREDITO 
        FROM VENTA
    ) AS VENTA 
GROUP BY VENTA.MES
ORDER BY VENTA.MES ASC
```

Comment: MES  CONTADO CREDITO
   05         26             0

Comment: Solo tengo data del mes de mayo

Comment: Si sacás de la query: `VENTA.MES, SUM(VENTA.CONTADO) AS CONTADO, SUM(VENTA.CREDITO) AS CREDITO` y lo reemplazás por `VENTA.MES` te devuelve los meses?

Comment: Claro los meses pero como no tengo data solo me devuelve del mes de mayo.

Comment: Y si en vez de ejecutar la suma mostras sólo el valor? `VENTA.MES, VENTA.CONTADO, VENTA.CREDITO` así. Esto tampoco te genera los meses vacíos?